# Mixing TypeScript internal and external modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, systemjs, typescript-typings

I know: "don't mix internal and external modules" but I must mix it :( 
I change big project where all modles are internal.

I have two files

MyFirstModule.ts

```
module Modules.Components {
   export class Best {          
    start() {
      // ...
    }    
     }
 }
export = Modules.Components.Best;
```

and file app.ts
Internal module

```
module App.Utils {
   export class Greeter {
    var a: Modules.Components.Best
    run(){
    lazyLoadingModule1=>(){
        a: new Modules.Components.Best
    }
  }     
 }
}
```

In app.ts i have a error "Cannot find namespace Modules".